# Is KMeans Clustering with higher dimensions possible?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a few hundred 3d arrays that I would like to do some clustering analysis with however `sklearn.cluster.KMeans` will only do a 2D array. Each of my arrays are size `(56,88,56)` and I have `300`. when I combine them as one array I get `(300,56,88,56)`. KMeans gives the error `ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.`. A way that I have worked around this is to use `np.ndarray.flatten()` on my array so my new array is `(275968,)` and when combined into one array I get `(300,275968)` and I am able to use KMeans clustering. Is there a way to perform clustering analysis with a 4D array or will I end up with the same or similar result as flattening the array for a 2D analysis?

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import nibabel as nib
import os, sys
from tqdm import tqdm

DIR = '(56x88x56)\\' 
flatten_list = []
for r,d,f in os.walk(DIR):
    for file in tqdm(f):
        path = DIR + file
        cp = nib.load(path).get_fdata()
        cp = np.array(cp)        
        array_flatten = np.ndarray.flatten(cp)
        flatten_list.append(array_flatten)

flatten_list = np.array(flatten_list)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 10, random_state = 0, verbose = 1).fit(flatten_list)
cluster_labels = kmeans.labels_
print(cluster_labels)
```

Answer (score 1):

The steps for K-Means clustering are:

- Picking some random centers: The same distribution is sampled for all coordinates, so this action is symmetric with respect to coordinates change.
- Computing distances between said clusters and points in the database. The formula for euclidian distance remains the same even if you change the order of coordinates.
- Computing averages and moving centers. Averages also remain the same when you interchange coordinates.

So to sum up, none of the steps in K-Means have anything to do with internal structure of your data. You could easily implement it for matrices, but there is no actual point to do so, since you can just flatten them and treat them as arrays. The solution sklearn converges to should be the same as the offered implementation.

Is there a special reason that you asked this? Does the sklearn solution not converge to the expected output?

Comment: You can easily pick three features (columns) as inputs to the variable that you fit.  

np.asarray([np.asarray(df['Feature1']),df['Feature2']),df['Feature3'])]).T
X = data

Let me know if you need more info.